# Git parameter in single pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use git parameter plugin to load branches into droplist in build with parameters option. But the problem is I cannot define git repo in the parameters section, only in the pipeline script? How to solve that? I'm not using a multibranch pipeline

The git repo is set in the pipeline:

```
git credentialsId: 'x', url: 'http://x.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot? There's a field called "Use repository".
[image]

Even without it git parameter will(should) use the first git repo defined in your job.

Comment: If it really catches the first defined repo in the pipeline then it would be great. I'll check it

Comment: But unfortunately when I have git ... declared in the pipeline with credentials etc, the branches aren't fetched and the list says that the git repo isn't set in the scm